# Book on smooth covering spaces

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, fundamental-groups, covering-spaces

Hi I am looking for a book (I need to cite it.) about smooth manifolds and covering spaces. I need the prove that action $\pi_1(M)$ on universal cover is smooth and the space of orbits $\widetilde{M}/\pi_1(M)$ is diffeomorphic to M. All I can find are these results in topological category. Any suggestions?

Comment: Presumably you can find this in Lee's Introduction to smooth manifolds. Anyway you can do this yourself: just define a differentiable structure on the universal cover so that the projection is a smooth submersion.

Comment: Not it's not there. Yes I know I can, however I need a citation.

Comment: I checked, and yes, it is inside the book I mentioned. Proposition 4.40 and Corollary 4.43.

Comment: Thank you, it is not exactly what I wanted, but very close. I found the answer in Morita though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a specific reference, but I can outline a program for you to proceed to prove both these things (I am assuming all manifolds are connected in what follows)

1. Show that given any smooth manifold $M$, there is a unique smooth structure on its universal cover $\tilde{M}$, for which the covering map $\pi : \tilde{M} \rightarrow M$ is a local diffeomorphism (or a smooth covering map, its the same smooth structure in the end).
2. Use that action of the fundamental group on the universal cover of $M$ corresponds to a deck transformation $d  : \tilde{M} \rightarrow \tilde{M}$. Then show that deck transformations are automatically smooth using the next point 3. (use 3. and the fact that a deck transformation is a lift of the covering map itself with respect to the same covering map)
3. Let $X$ be a smooth manifold with universal cover $\tilde{X}$. Then for any smooth map $f  : Z \rightarrow X$, if $f$ has a lift with respect to the covering map $\pi : \tilde{X} \rightarrow X$, say $\tilde{f} : Z \rightarrow \tilde{X}$, then $\tilde{f}$ is smooth (use the $\pi$ is a local diffeomorphism and $\pi \circ \tilde{f} = f$ to prove this).

Finally, to show that $\tilde{M} / \pi_{1}(M)$ is diffeomorphic to $M$, you may trace through the proof of the quotient manifold theorem (see e.g. Theorem 9.19 of his *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*),  and apply it to the zero dimensional lie group of deck transformations. This gives a unique smooth structure on the quotient space, such that the quotient map is a smooth covering map (or you could just do this directly, check that there is a unique smooth structure on $\tilde{M} / \pi_{1}(M)$ such that the quotient map $\pi : \tilde{M} \rightarrow \tilde{M} / \pi_{1}(M)$ is a smooth covering map). Then check, using this smooth structure, that the map $\tilde{M} / \pi_{1}(M) \rightarrow M$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you really just need a citations, everything can be found in John M. Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, Second Edition.
Here is the list you need:

- the smooth structure on the universal cover is given by Proposition 4.40 and Corollary 4.43.
- the fact that the fundamental group of a smooth manifold acts freely, smoothly and properly is a particular case of Proposition 21.12.
- assuming you already know that the quotient map is an homeomorphism, the fact that it is a diffeomorphism is a consequence of Theorem 21.13.

Comment: That is for one part if I understand it correctly, but not for the part that action of fundamental group is smooth

Comment: @AndražMaier See my edit

Comment: I see, now I understand. Thank you.